# unbound DNS without recursive

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, unbound

I want to configure the unbound DNS for the domain e.g. `domain.com` in a way that it only answers for *.domain.com and rest of any query like gmail.com or hotmail.com are refused.
I have following configuration but it doesn't work as desired.

```
server:
interface: a.b.c.d (public IP)
verbosity: 2
logfile: "unbound.log"
log-queries: yes
hide-identity: yes
hide-version: yes
access-control: 127.0.0.1/8 allow
access-control: 192.168.0.0/24 allow
access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 refuse_non_local

local-zone: "domain.com" transparent
forward-zone:
name: "domain.com"
forward-addr: 192.168.0.1    #### local DNS server
```

So the idea is that the query comes on the live/public interface (IP a.b.c.d) for a zone `domain.com`, the query is forwarded to the local DNS `192.168.0.1` and then the answer is forwarded to `a.b.c.d` which is then sent to the client/internet. If the query arrives for lets say `gmail.com` on `a.b.c.d` then `REFUSED` should be answer like following

```
** server can't find gmail.com: REFUSED
```

I am not able to achieve REFUSED for the `domains(e.g. gmail/hotmail)` other than `domain.com`
In a nut shell I can't get `access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 refuse_non_local` to work

Comment: Does your DNS server have internet access or is there any block rule to deny 53. port? Unbound needs to connect root hints server to resolve domains which it doesn't know.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I want to achieve, in a nut shell I can't get "access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 refuse_non_local" to work

Comment: You can change the config as below. First line is being rejected all of other queries and second line accepts only listed domains. I hope it is work for you.

`local-zone: "." refuse
local-zone: "domain.com" transparent
local-zone: "domain2.com" transparent`

Comment: Thanks librhnylmz, your solution works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

librhnylmz solution worked.
Following is working.

```
server:
interface: a.b.c.d (public IP)
verbosity: 2
logfile: "unbound.log"
log-queries: yes
extended-statistics: no
access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 allow
local-zone: "." refuse 
local-zone: "domain.com." transparent
forward-zone:
name: "domain.com"
forward-addr: 192.168.0.1 ### Local DNS
```